# Heating cartridge characteristic curve?

Tags: heat, device-characteristics

I was wondering if there are heating cartrdiges out there which have a characteristic curve how the heating temperature depends on the heating power. E.g. a x/y plot with the heating power in Watts as x and the temperature in °C as y. Or with the heating cartridge "assembled" in ambient air. Or do I have to characterize every single heating cartridge myself?

Comment: Not a chance. Temperature depends not just on heat input, but on heat capacity of whatever's being heated, and heat flow via conduction, convection and radiation to the surrounding environment. Calculating all that isn't simple.

Comment: I'd argue that calculating this should be even impossible. And as far as I can remember correctly FEM simulations in which not little effort has been put into during studies have not been accurate enough as well in many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energy you put in will be converted to thermal energy, distributed among the thermal mass. No energy is lost.

So, for a given energy input, you will get a certain temperature difference compared to before, which will then be transported away depending on the thermal conductivity of the interfaces between the actual heating element and anything connected to it.

This, again, is a linear process, depending on temperature difference. The cartridge is likely designed to have a hot side with good thermal conductivity, and the other sides are meant to stay cool.

Your limits are given by the maximum power rating of the components and the maximum temperature -- these are the points where you're supposed to stop feeding more energy in.

If thermal conductivity of what you've connected is bad, you can hit the maximum temperature, but stay well below the maximum power -- the temperature just keeps increasing, but can't go anywhere.

If thermal conductivity of what you've connected is good, you can hit the maximum power but stay below the maximum temperature -- any heat you generate is carried away instantly.

Somewhere in the middle between that is where you want to be, that's not defined by the cartridge however, but by whatever you connect to it.

Comment: Great, thanks for the hints.